# Error de ubicación en configuración DNS con Bind

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ldap

Estoy intentando configurar un DNS en Ubuntu 18.04 con Bind. En concreto, he configurado el archivo named.conf.options de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues bien, si intento comprobar si la sintaxis es correcta, me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, el directorio existe  y es visible.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo resolverlo?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: creo que tienes que poner el directorio de forma absoluta. ahi le estas diciendo la carpeta `var/cache/bin` y esto suele ser con la barra inicial: `/var/cache/bin`

Comment: Cierto. En efecto ahí estaba el problema. Muchas gracias :D